# Glossaries: Print first occurence by using ACRONYM (DESC)

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

Is there a way to change the way how the acronyms in `glossaries` package are printed on the first occurence when defining them via `\newacronym{cd}{CD}{compact disk}`. Currently I'm using the following to achieve it:

```
\newglossaryentry{BLAS}{%
  type=\acronymtype, 
  name={BLAS}, 
  description={Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms}, 
  first={\glstext*{BLAS} (\glsdesc*{BLAS})}%
}
```

which works, but is somehow to quite optimal yet since I need to particularly set the `first`-item. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\defglsdisplayfirst` to change the format applied to an acronym when it is referenced the first time:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}[2011/04/12]

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \defglsdisplayfirst[\acronymtype]{%
    \glsentryshort{\glslabel} (\glsentrylong{\glslabel})#4%
  }%
}

\newacronym{BLAS}{BLAS}{Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossary

\noindent
The \gls{BLAS} are \ldots

\end{document}
```

The resulting output is:

[image]

Comment: Please note that `glsdisplayfirst` has been deprecated. See page 105 in [the documentation](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you look into section **13.3 Defining A Custom Acronym Style** of the [`glossaries` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf#page=162), you will find what you need.

An example of this code can be found in: http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples/sample-custom-acronym.tex.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered some problems with `glsdisplayfirst` (extra spaces after acronyms). Here is my solution using `newacronymstyle` (based on `glossaries` official sample code [sam­ple-cus­tom-acronym.tex](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/samples)):

[image: Latex output]

```
\documentclass[hidelinks]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

%define new style:
\newacronymstyle{custom-fn}% new style name
{% Check for long form in case of a mixed glossary
  \ifglshaslong{\glslabel}{\glsgenacfmt}{\glsgenentryfmt}%
}%
{% Style definitions:
 \glshyperfirstfalse
 % Redefine the commands used by \glsgenacfmt on first use:
  \renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \glsentryshort{##1} (\glsentrylong{##1})##2%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \Glsentryshort{##1} (\Glsentrylong{##1})##2%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \glsentryshortpl{##1} (\glsentrylongpl{##1})##2%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\Genplacrfullformat}[2]{%
   \Glsentryshortpl{##1} (\Glsentrylongpl{##1})##2%
  }%
}

% Now set the new acronym style (to override the default style)
\setacronymstyle{custom-fn}

% Set an appropriate glossary style:
\setglossarystyle{altlist}

% Now define the acronyms (must be done after setting the custom
% style)
\newacronym{blas}{BLAS}{Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
%\printglossaries

\noindent
First occurence of \gls{blas}.

\noindent
And second occurence of \gls{blas}.


\end{document}
```