# Acronym package: Swap short and long form

Tags: acronyms, pandoc

Apologies for creating a duplicate question: I exactly want to achieve what @eDeviser asks in [Acronym, swap description and acronym](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288167/acronym-swap-description-and-acronym/288328?newreg=eef67bf82e65467ebe84eb7493bf0233) but due to my low reputation, I cannot collaborate there:
How to swap the short and long form (putting the long form in parentheses) of an acronym when used for the first time? After that just the short form should be displayed.

I struggle incorporating the suggested solution by @clemens (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288328/118158). I use Rmarkdown and pandoc to generate a pdf but get the following error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.165 ...ring{\protect\@acf{#1}}{#1 (\AC@acl{#1})}

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
```

relevant parts of **Master.Rmd** with YAML snippet:

````
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage[nohyperlinks, printonlyused]{acronym}
---
```{r child = 'Abstract.Rmd'}
```
```{r child = 'Abbreviations.Rmd'}
```
````

**Abbreviations.Rmd**

```
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{API}[API]{application programming interface}
\end{acronym}
```

**Abstract.Rmd** based on @clemens solution

```
\makeatletter
% singular:
\renewcommand*{\acfa}[1]{%
  \texorpdfstring{\protect\@acf{#1}}{#1 (\AC@acl{#1})}%
}
\renewcommand*{\@acf}[1]{%
  \acffont{%
    \AC@placelabel{#1}%
    \acfsfont{\acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}}}%
    \nolinebreak[3] %
    (\AC@acl{#1})%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\ac{API}\newline
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by making the changes directly in the original `acronym.sty` file that in my case is located at `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acronym`.

I do not understand why the `\renewcommand` way did not work, though.